# Does Grails's failOnError force a flush?

Tags: grails, groovy, persistence, grails-orm

In Grails if I do:

```
domainObj.save(failOnError: true)
```

will that implicitly flush Hibernate's buffer as well, as if "flush:true" were added to the args? If you can please provide a credible source for your answer, thanks.

Comment: No better credible source than the source code :-)

Comment: The save method informs the persistence context that an instance should be saved or updated. The object will not be persisted immediately unless the flush argument is used:

Refer : http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the code in [AbstractSavePersistentMethod](https://github.com/spring-projects/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/metaclass/AbstractSavePersistentMethod.java) the validate occurs before the save/flush, so if it fails and failOnError is true, the ValidationException will be thrown and **no flush will occur**.

```
if (errors.hasErrors()) {
  handleValidationError(domainClass,target,errors);
  boolean shouldFail = shouldFail(application, domainClass);
  if (argsMap != null && argsMap.containsKey(ARGUMENT_FAIL_ON_ERROR)) {
    shouldFail = GrailsClassUtils.getBooleanFromMap(ARGUMENT_FAIL_ON_ERROR, argsMap);
  }
  if (shouldFail) {
    throw new ValidationException("Validation Error(s) occurred during save()", errors);
  }
  return null;
}
...
return performSave(target, shouldFlush); //here flush can happen
```